# How do I call triggerHandler with a specific fake 'event' parameter?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to test that on a link click 'preventDefault' is called. However, I have difficulties to replace a real 'event' object with one I can spy on:

Here is how I trigger the click event:

```
var e = jasmine.createSpyObj('e', [ 'preventDefault' ]);
$element.triggerHandler('click', [e]);
```

However, when the directive code is being run, the event element is not replaced with a fake one:

```
$element.on('click', function(event) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

I tried different ways of adding a second parameter to triggerHandler - as an array, as an object, just some line, etc. Neither worked.. It is also not that many examples of triggerHandler together with additional parameters, so I feel a little bit lost...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs say that `triggerHandler()` passes a dummy object to the handler: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

If you check the source, you can see that `triggerHandler()` creates its own event object, and then passes your second argument as the event data, not the actual event object:

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/jqLite.js#L882

Relevant code:

```
var event = [{
  preventDefault: noop,
  stopPropagation: noop
}];

forEach(eventFns, function(fn) {
  fn.apply(element, event.concat(eventData));
});
```

I've used jQuery's internal event simulator for creating my own events. That may work for you: http://wingkaiwan.com/2012/09/23/triggering-mouse-events-with-jquery-simulate-when-testing-in-javascript/

Answer (score 27):

We also ran into this issue when we wanted to pass an event for testing that had a specific value for the `which` property.

As c0bra pointed out, the `triggerHandler` function creates its own dummy event object which it then passes on to the event handler. However, you can take advantage of the fact that the `triggerHandler` function will extend the dummy event with an event object passed in if there is a valued `type` property on the event:
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.5/src/jqLite.js#L1043

```
triggerHandler: function(element, event, extraParameters) {
    ...
    // If a custom event was provided then extend our dummy event with it
    if (event.type) {
        dummyEvent = extend(dummyEvent, event);
    }
    ...
}
```

After inspecting the Angular code, we found that when you call `element.triggerHandler` from your test, it will first call an anonymous function which *then* calls Angular's `triggerHandler` function. When Angular's `triggerHandler` function is called, it is passed the element as the first argument, then the first argument that you passed to `triggerHandler` in your test as the second argument, then your second argument that you passed to `triggerHandler` as the third etc. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.6.5/src/jqLite.js#L1068

What that then means is you can pass an object to `triggerHandler` in your test as the first argument, and that object's properties will be appended to the dummy event object (or overwritten if there was already a property on the dummy object with the same name), thus allowing you to pass specific values and add spies for testing.

Note that the event type will need to be passed to `triggerHandler` as the type  property on your object so as to satisfy the if condition mentioned above. As an example, this is how we used `triggerHandler` in our test:

```
element.triggerHandler({
    type: 'keydown',
    which: 13
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I was trying `element.triggerHandler('keydown', { which: 27 })` but changing to `element.triggerHandler({ type: 'keydown', which: 27 })` as you mentioned fixed the issue.

Comment: Hurry to Lisa! 

I was also using elm.triggerHandler ('keydown', {which:13}); and your way worked perfect.

One thing to add . . . event.which returns an integer so I had to remove the single quotes on the which value to get it to work with my implementation:

elm.triggerHandler({type: 'keydown', which: 13 });

Comment: element.triggerHandler({ type: 'keydown', keyCode: 27 }) worked for me. element.triggerHandler('keydown', {keyCode: 27 }) did not. IMO this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Lisa, when you link to source in repository, do not link to branches (*master* in this case) as this is a **moving target** but to specific commits or tags which are stable. I fixed links to source in the answer, pointing them to current newest version 1.6.5.