# Using JQLite How to select an item or items in a select box

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, karma-jasmine, jqlite

I'm attempting to highlight 1 or more items in a select box in a unit test. I'm using Karma, Jasmine, and PhantomJS, AngularJS, JQLite, CoffeeScript.

My list has items ["banana", "apple", "orange"].

I tried setting the value directly:

```
sourceList = element.find('select').eq(1)
sourceList.val("[banana]").triggerHandler('change');
// Or
sourceList.val("banana").triggerHandler('change');
```

When I get sourceList.val() it's not set.

I tried triggering events to select it. Note I can't do a "click" event because I have another event fire on click.

```
sourceList.find('option').eq(0).triggerHandler("active");
sourceList.find('option').eq(0).triggerHandler("focus");
sourceList.find('option').eq(0).triggerHandler("drag");
sourceList.find('option').eq(0).triggerHandler("dragLeave");
```

I tried using the `selectedIndex`

```
sourceList.selectedIndex = 1
```

None of those seem to highlight or select the item. I'm out of ideas. Has anyone accomplished this?

Here is the method of the directive which I am trying to test:

```
// Clicks on the add button. Should take all items highlighted and move them over
   $scope.add = function(){
        var sourceList = $element.find('select').eq(1);
        angular.forEach(sourceList.val(), function(val, index){
             $scope.selected.push({
                    text: val
             });
         });
         checkListDupes();
     };
```

This code works when I do it manually in the browser but I can't seem to get my test to highlight some items in the select box before clicking the add button. So when this code executes sourceList.val() is equal to [].

Comment: could you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22333324/2435473

Comment: I don't think that solves my problem. I actually have it working with click events. The problem is that I can't get select element's options to select via jQlite.

Comment: can you provide your directive?

Comment: I unfortunately can't share the entire directive but I added the particular method that I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late to the party, but I'll leave it here for anyone else with the same problem.
I don't know how you've built the options for the select box but `sourceList.val("banana").triggerHandler('change');`
should work fine as long as the value of the option is banana. If you haven't specified a track by on the ng-options, the default values that angular creates will be `'string:'+<option label>` so `sourceList.val('string:banana').triggerHandler('change');` should do the trick.