# pass event to triggerHandler in angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-material, dom-events

I want the same menu to appear when clicking on multiple different buttons.

How can I pass the original click event to the new created triggered event?

This is what I do today:

```
this.openMenuFromOther = function(event) {
  $timeout(function() {
    var ele = document.getElementById('userMenu');
    angular.element(ele).triggerHandler('click');
  }, 0);
}
```

In the demo you can see it creates a new event which doesn't correspond with the original click event and the menu opens on the main button and not on the clicked button.

[CODEPEN DEMO](https://codepen.io/mikila85/pen/oWjZdx)

Comment: Possible duplicate [how-do-i-call-triggerhandler-with-a-specific-fake-event-parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332338/how-do-i-call-triggerhandler-with-a-specific-fake-event-parameter)

Comment: nope, i've been there and it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you are trying to achieve here? As far as I can see, you get exactly the behaviour you can expect: you trigger the click handler of another button, so the menu is opened from that 'triggered' button.

Comment: updated the question to hold this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is: **you can't**.

Angular has no intent of giving you the option to reuse it. You can see this is their [source code](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/1e4ba35d4d7b3ec15b482863a6d60def1b760117/src/components/menu/js/menuController.js#L236). `$scope.$mdMenu = {}` returns a different scope and therefore prevents you from changing any variable. Even "hacky" ways are really hard to find.

You would have to change `menuContainer` and `triggerElement` to your new trigger and then at the end change it back. But as mentioned, it would be really ugly to do so.

The cleanest **solution** is to make a template.

The template contains the menu you want to reuse. (this should be inside the `<body ng-app="MyApp">`)

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="menu">
   <md-menu md-offset="0 60">
      ...
   </md-menu>
</script>
```

You then make a directive, e.g.

```
.directive('mdMenuButton', function($compile, $templateCache) {
  return {
    restrict: 'M',
    replace: 'true',
    template: $templateCache.get('menu')
    // as of now "templateUrl" doesn't work in this case
  }
})
```

You are now able to reuse this code as many times as you want like this

```
<!--directive: md-menu-button -->
<br/> different stuff not related
<br/> different stuff not related

<!--directive: md-menu-button -->
<br/> different stuff not related
```

Comment: yes in the end i used ng-include just for the content of md-menu-content. it solved it (because i need different buttons) thx :)

Answer (score -1):

Please forgive me for my poor English

I try　it. if you set params at triggerHandler function,then cannot get params at directive ng-click! The context is not an initial context in an angular event directive,the context is scope object,and extend a object {$event:event},where event is a current click event!

here is source snippet code:

```js
element.on(eventName, function (event) {
    var callback = function () {
      fn(scope, {$event: event});
    };
    if (forceAsyncEvents[eventName] && $rootScope.$$phase) {
      scope.$evalAsync(callback);
    } else {
      scope.$apply(callback);
    }
});
```

I think these way can do it:

1. first way;

```js
this.openMenuFromOther = function(event) {
      $scope.$menuEvent=event;
      $timeout(function() {
        var ele = document.getElementById('userMenu');
        angular.element(ele).triggerHandler('click');
      }, 0);
    }
```

use it like this:

```html
  <md-button id="userMenu" aria-label="Open phone interactions menu" 
ng-click="ctrl.openMenu($mdMenu, $menuEvent)">
        Click here to open menu
</md-button>
```

2. you can save  event data on controller or element or other global object.

Comment: i tried it: https://codepen.io/mikila85/pen/zwrqMo not working. can you please fix there?

Comment: inject $scope like $timeout

Comment: inject $scope like $timeout,  at html: <md-button id="userMenu" aria-label="Open phone interactions menu" ng-click="ctrl.openMenu($mdMenu, $menuEvent)">

Comment: yes i did here: https://codepen.io/mikila85/pen/PmZNVx not working :( .. can you please edit it?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you more!

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PmZzoL  , the question:How can I pass the original click event to the new created triggered event? does the console cannot get event.target element ?

Comment: i tried but not working. menu still opens on main button instead of the actual clicked button.